# Symfony 3 firewall protected area confusion

Tags: symfony, authentication, firewall

I want to protect by the firewall and so by login / session an application area in Symfony 3:

```
security:   
    firewalls:
        seller:
            pattern: ^/somearea
            form_login:
                login_path: /somearea/login
                check_path: /somearea/login
            logout:
                path: /somearea/logout
                target: /
            anonymous: false

access_control:
    - { path: ^/somearea/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/somearea, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

But when I want to go to the /somearea area then the app gets confused and will be "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" and if I will (what actually I dont want) have that login at not behind the area (eg. /some2login or whatever different) then says the login must be starting with /somearea.

How can I solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are disallowing anonymous access by setting `anonymous: false`, that is why the access_control will not go into effect. The simplest solution is probably to just change that setting to `anonymous: ~`, since your fallback access control for `^/somearea` will ensure that no anonymous user is allowed.

Another solution would be to have a separate firewall just for login:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern: ^/somearea/login$
            security: false
        seller:
            pattern: ^/somearea
            form_login:
                login_path: /somearea/login
                check_path: /somearea/login_check
            ...
```

The login form will fall into the first firewall which is unsecured and always accessible, but when submitting the form you will send a request to `/somearea/login_check` which does not match the first firewall, but the second one and therefore authentication is attempted for the secured seller-area.